# Display straight HTML from C# MVC model data to CSHTML page? or add HTML line breaks server side?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, model, server-side-rendering

Is there a way to display straight HTML from C# MVC model data to CSHTML page? or to add HTML line breaks server side?

Is there a way to display straight HTML from C# MVC model data using `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` or is there an `@Html.DisplayNameAsHTMLFor()` method?

## Model has the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

public class PersonObjModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "I AGREE")]
    public bool IAgree { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "<br />Welcome! <br />What is your name?")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

How do I display these HTML breaks in my Web page, 
 so it doesn't display the HTML as text?

## .CSHTML page had the following:

```
@model HoldemCore.Models.PersonObjModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IAgree)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <input type="checkbox" id="IAgree" name="IAgree"
           @if (Model.IAgree) { "checked value=\"true\"".ToString(); }
           @if (!Model.IAgree) { "value=\"false\"".ToString(); }
           onchange="this.value = this.checked;" />
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
  </fieldset>
}
```

checked values were not displaying in source correctly & HTML was showing up as text in [Display(Name] for [Name] field

## .CSHTML page has the following.. @Html.Raw() is the answer

@model HoldemCore.Models.PersonObjModel

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IAgree)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <input type="checkbox" id="IAgree" name="IAgree"
           @if (Model.IAgree) { @Html.Raw("checked value=\"true\""); }
           @if (!Model.IAgree) { @Html.Raw("value=\"false\""); }
           onchange="this.value = this.checked;" />
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Raw(@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name))
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
  </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## .CSHTML page has the following.. @Html.Raw() is the answer

@model HoldemCore.Models.PersonObjModel

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IAgree)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <input type="checkbox" id="IAgree" name="IAgree"
           @if (Model.IAgree) { @Html.Raw("checked value=\"true\""); }
           @if (!Model.IAgree) { @Html.Raw("value=\"false\""); }
           onchange="this.value = this.checked;" />
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Raw(@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name))
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
  </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Don't post it into answer

Comment: felt this was an important reference item that was needed on this site.

Comment: I used the Q & A at the same time feature for this post. I'll need more clarity on what needs to be updated, as I'm not seeing any options like [Accept Answer] here